# What's wrong with my Swift function?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a dice roll game and I'm having issues getting certain rolls to show up. Currently it's incomplete, but my current rolls I've written code for aren't showing up properly. i.e. rolling a 4 presents a 3. I understand I need to refactor and I apologize for that abomination that is my function.

edit : It is incomplete at the moment... so I haven't added scenarios for the other rolls.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var one: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var two: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var three: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var four: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var five: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var six: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var seven: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelThree: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFour: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFive: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelSix: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        labelOne.isHidden = true
        labelTwo.isHidden = true
        labelThree.isHidden = true
        labelFour.isHidden = true
        labelFive.isHidden = true
        labelSix.isHidden = true

        one.isHidden = true
        two.isHidden = true
        three.isHidden = true
        four.isHidden = true
        five.isHidden = true
        six.isHidden = true
        seven.isHidden = true

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // Rearrange dice depending on what is rolled.
    func rearrangeDie(){
        if randomDiceRoll() == 1 {
            six.isHidden = false
        } else if six.isHidden == false {
            six.isHidden = true }
        if randomDiceRoll() == 2 {
            one.isHidden = false
            seven.isHidden = false }
        else if one.isHidden == false &&
        seven.isHidden == false {
            self.one.isHidden = true
            self.seven.isHidden = true
        }
        if randomDiceRoll() == 3 {
            one.isHidden = false
            six.isHidden = false
            seven.isHidden = false }
        else if one.isHidden == false && six.isHidden == false && seven.isHidden == false {
            one.isHidden = true
            six.isHidden = true
            seven.isHidden = true
        }







    }





    // Reveal labels as you roll
    func textToLabel(roll:intmax_t)     {

        let diceScore = String(roll)
        if labelOne.isHidden == true {
            labelOne.text = diceScore
            labelOne.isHidden = false


        }
    }

    @IBAction func dice(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }


    @IBAction func dieButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        randomDiceRoll()

        rearrangeDie()
        print(randomDiceRoll())

    }
        // Returns back a random Int (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6)
    func randomDiceRoll() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
    }




}
```

Comment: Please ensure that you provide a [mcve] -- that is to say, code that is complete enough to let someone else verify the problem and check their solution (but no more complete than the bare minimum needed for that purpose!)

Comment: This not only means that all code you post should be relevant, but also that you should post all relevant code! Please provide the code for the 'randomDiceRoll' function.

Comment: (it's not presently obvious why the code is expected to work -- why would you hide only one and seven on a roll of two?; trying to make a more obvious implementation is also likely to lead to a less buggy one).

Comment: @Sty, ...*unless* an implementation of `randomDiceRoll()` that only ever returns 4 suffices to show the problem -- in that case, replacing the random elements with a hardcoded value would be entirely appropriate.

Comment: Rolling a 4 presents a 3?

Comment: apologies folks.

Answer (score 0):

To many if statements in your code make it hard to read. Your sample is not complete and so is probably your question. Therefore I can just assume the following:

- You want to display the dice roll as "eyes" or "dots"
- Each dot is a UIView
- Numbering is from top left to bottom, the center dot is number 7

So heres my suggested code:

```
func rearrangeDie(){

  let roll = randomDiceRoll()

  //1x2
  //374
  //5x6

  //One is visible for 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6
  //oxx
  //xxx
  //xxx
  one.isHidden = roll == 1

  //Two is visible for 4, 5 and 6
  //xxo
  //xxx
  //xxx
  two.isHidden = roll == 1 || roll == 2 || roll == 3

  //...

  //Seven is visible for 1, 3 and 5
  //xxx
  //xox
  //xxx
  seven.isHidden = roll == 2 || roll == 4 || roll == 6
}
```